# Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, crash, sigabrt

```
 Incident Identifier: B959CD08-FA2C-4A34-8D0C-343927FF6B86
 CrashReporter Key:   78e6625f679cb4cfb76f553075c64a197002c1bf
 Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
 Process:         ktv [50343]
 Path:
 /var/mobile/Applications/B8971D06-6001-49F7-81E1-8B88CDA5EB03/ktv.app/ktv
 Identifier:      ktv
 Version:         ??? (???)
 Code Type:       ARM (Native)
 Parent Process:  launchd [1]

 Date/Time:       2013-01-09 18:59:32.193 +0800
 OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
 Report Version:  104

 Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
 Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
 Crashed Thread:  0

 Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
 Thread 0 Crashed:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30da732c __pthread_kill + 8
 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x33338208 pthread_kill + 48
 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x33331298 abort + 88
 3   libc++abi.dylib                    0x377c1f64 abort_message + 40
 4   libc++abi.dylib                    0x377bf3ea _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE +114
 5   libc++abi.dylib                    0x377bf44a std::terminate() + 14
 6   libc++abi.dylib                    0x377c081e __cxa_rethrow + 82
 7   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x334772a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
 8   CoreFoundation                 0x3809c506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
 9   CoreFoundation                 0x3809c366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
 10  GraphicsServices               0x3657f432 GSEventRunModal + 130
 11  UIKit                          0x30f4dcce UIApplicationMain + 1074
 12  ktv                                0x000af9b0 0xa6000 + 39344
 13  ktv                                0x000a86c0 0xa6000 + 9920

 Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
 Thread 1:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30d973a8 kevent + 24
 1   libdispatch.dylib              0x34a71f04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
 2   libdispatch.dylib              0x34a71c22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

 Thread 2 name:  WebThread
 Thread 2:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30d97004 mach_msg_trap + 20
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30d971fa mach_msg + 50
 2   CoreFoundation                 0x3811a3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
 3   CoreFoundation                 0x38119124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
 4   CoreFoundation                 0x3809c49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
 5   CoreFoundation                 0x3809c366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
 6   WebCore                            0x31524c9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
 7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f972e _pthread_start + 314
 8   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f95e8 thread_start + 0

 Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
 Thread 3:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30d97004 mach_msg_trap + 20
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30d971fa mach_msg + 50
 2   CoreFoundation                 0x3811a3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
 3   CoreFoundation                 0x38119124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
 4   CoreFoundation                 0x3809c49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
 5   CoreFoundation                 0x3809c366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
 6   Foundation                     0x372d7bb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader)_resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
 7   Foundation                     0x372d7a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
 8   Foundation                     0x3736b58a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
 9   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f972e _pthread_start + 314
 10  libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f95e8 thread_start + 0

 Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
 Thread 4:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30da7570 __select + 20
 1   CoreFoundation                 0x3811e63a __CFSocketManager + 726
 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f972e _pthread_start + 314
 3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f95e8 thread_start + 0

 Thread 5:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30d97004 mach_msg_trap + 20
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30d971fa mach_msg + 50
 2   CoreFoundation                 0x3811a3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
 3   CoreFoundation                 0x38119124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
 4   CoreFoundation                 0x3809c49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
 5   CoreFoundation                 0x3809c366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
 6   ktv                                0x0011683c 0xa6000 + 460860
 7   Foundation                     0x372d7a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
 8   Foundation                     0x3736b58a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
 9   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f972e _pthread_start + 314
 10  libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f95e8 thread_start + 0

 Thread 6:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30da7628 __semwait_signal + 24
 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332fdb1a nanosleep + 138
 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x33308608 sleep + 40
 3   ktv                                0x000b09fa 0xa6000 + 43514
 4   Foundation                     0x372d7a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
 5   Foundation                     0x3736b58a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
 6   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f972e _pthread_start + 314
 7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f95e8 thread_start + 0

 Thread 7 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
 Thread 7:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30d97004 mach_msg_trap + 20
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30d971fa mach_msg + 50
 2   CoreFoundation                 0x3811a3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
 3   CoreFoundation                 0x38119124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
 4   CoreFoundation                 0x3809c49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
 5   CoreFoundation                 0x3809c366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
 6   WebCore                            0x3154e0d2 _ZN7WebCoreL15runLoaderThreadEPv + 122
 7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f972e _pthread_start + 314
 8   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f95e8 thread_start + 0

 Thread 8 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
 Thread 8:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30da7068 __psynch_cvwait + 24
 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f9a46 _pthread_cond_wait + 634
 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f97c2 pthread_cond_wait + 34
 3   CoreMedia                      0x35d3a868 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 268
 4   MediaToolbox                   0x329233e6 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 22
 5   CoreMedia                      0x35d598b4 figThreadMain + 168
 6   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f972e _pthread_start + 314
 7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f95e8 thread_start + 0

 Thread 9:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30da7cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f3f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f3cc8 start_wqthread + 0

 Thread 10:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30da7cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f3f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f3cc8 start_wqthread + 0

 Thread 11:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30da7cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f3f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f3cc8 start_wqthread + 0

 Thread 12:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30da7cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f3f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f3cc8 start_wqthread + 0

 Thread 13:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x30da7cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f3f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x332f3cc8 start_wqthread + 0

 Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
     r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
        r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ec73d98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fea4acc
            r8: 0x2fea4870    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x0000000a     r11:
            0x00000009
                ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fea4ac0      lr: 0x3333820f      pc:
                0x30da732c
                  cpsr: 0x00080010

                  Binary Images:
                     0xa6000 -   0x264fff +ktv armv7
                     <071d076aba693352b8ae722bd01cace1>
                     /var/mobile/Applications/B8971D06-6001-49F7-81E1-8B88CDA5EB03/ktv.app/ktv
                       0x2eb000 -   0x2ebfff +MobileSubstrate.dylib armv6
                       <d8da1cc9b8ea37cfba03a60549cdac4c>
                       /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib
                         0x322000 -   0x323fff +SubstrateLoader.dylib armv6
                         <825b732151e6379b9cbec6e597a986fa>
                         /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib
                         0x2fea5000 - 0x2fec6fff  dyld armv7
                         <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
                         0x30625000 - 0x30625fff  vecLib armv7
                         <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465>
                         /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
                         0x306ef000 - 0x306f6fff  SpringBoardUI armv7
                         <84e082f96770383096a5b083841d3f59>
                         /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardUI.framework/SpringBoardUI
                         0x306f7000 - 0x307cffff  vImage armv7
                         <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0>
                         /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
                         0x30800000 - 0x3080afff  libvMisc.dylib armv7
                         <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d>
                         /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
                         0x3080d000 - 0x30842fff  DataAccess armv7
                         <89fd0c22338b37538cf61803a0bca9e2>
                         /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
                         0x30882000 - 0x308dffff  StoreServices armv7
                         <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d>
                         /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
                         0x308e0000 - 0x30ba1fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7
                         <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2>
                         /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
                         0x30bb3000 - 0x30bbbfff  MobileWiFi armv7
                         <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72>
                         /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
                         0x30bbe000 - 0x30be3fff  OpenCL armv7
```

Does anyone know anything about this crash? That all the infomation here, I still dont know whats wrong about it. The important is that I found many crash contain this part, But it may caused many reasons.

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30da732c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33338208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33331298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x377c1f64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x377bf3ea _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 114
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x377bf44a std::terminate() + 14
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x377c081e __cxa_rethrow + 82
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x334772a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3809c506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3809c366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
10  GraphicsServices                0x3657f432 GSEventRunModal + 130
11  UIKit                           0x30f4dcce UIApplicationMain + 1074
12  ktv                             0x000af9b0 0xa6000 + 39344
13  ktv                             0x000a86c0 0xa6000 + 9920
```

Can I understand that this part is not the really point where my app crashes?

Answer (score 20):

It's not a crash, it's an abort due to an exception. It means that your application is passing bad data to a system routine and the routine is saying that it's bad and can't continue, so it's killing your app. The console should show something about what went wrong. One common exception that can occur is attempting to get the n + 1st object from an array with only n objects in it. (For example getting the 5th element of an `NSArray` when there are only 4 elements.) The console will have a message that says just that. So check the console to see what might have happened.

Comment: Do you mean, how did I find the error message? If so, it's in the console window in the debugger when running your application in Xcode. It may also be in the log file you got the stack trace from above. If you download the console logs from the device, it should also be there.

Comment: I got this crash log from some device, but I don't know what does it means. So how did you know it is an "abort do to an exception"? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Because the top of the stack says `pthread_kill`, it means that the program or an OS routine that the program called told the OS to kill the app. A little further down, you can see the call to `abort`, which indicates that the program, or an OS routine specifically attempted to abort execution. Further down, in stack frame 7, you can see `objc_exception_rethrow`, which means that an Objective-C exception was thrown. The way to fix it is to find out what the exception is by making it happen on another device (or simulator), or getting the full console logs from that device.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is the full console log I got from a device. Do you means that I must see the crash when I run it durning debugging? And is it helps me to find the crash in another device?

Comment: Is the device normally connected to a Mac? If so, you can open up Console.app, click "Show Log List", and in the list of logs, under "Files", twirl open "~/Library/Logs" (assuming it's the user who owns the device that's logged in), then twirl open "CrashReporter", then scroll down and twirl open "MobileDevice". You should see a list of all the iOS devices that user has plugged into their computer. You can then select the appropriate one, twirl it open, and you'll see all the logs for various apps including yours.

Comment: So you're saying the app is aborted because some of my code is wrong? or it's natural? What's difference between crash and exception?

Comment: It usually happens because your code is wrong. It can happen, for example, if you have an NSArray with a single element and you try to access element #2. The difference is that a crash happens when the OS decides to abort your program because it did something illegal like accessing memory that doesn't exist, or that your process doesn't have permission to access. An exception occurs when you pass a library, function or method bad data, and that library, function, or method decides it can't continues and asks the OS to abort the process. (Some types of exceptions can be handled, but some abort)

Answer (score 0):

Solved !!

I have solved this issue :
replace below files files from your project file(if you have backup of your project):

1. pods
2. projectname.xcworkspace
3. podfile.lock, podfile
4. add pods in podfile if any pod missing and install pods
5. Build your project and run

Please get project backup in zip this will help to solve this error.

Answer (score -4):

I had deleted my Main.storyboard and had replaced it with the storyboard from another project. My solution was to delete my project and recreate it.