# iOS Mystery crash w libsystem_kernel.dylib

Tags: ios, iphone, sigabrt, crashlytics

The report I'm getting back from *Crashlytics* is

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
SIGABRT ABORT at 0x357fedf0
```

How do I narrow this mystery crash down?

Also, here's some additional info from *Crashlytics*

[image: Crashlytics dashboard]

## EDIT

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3b90f350 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x3b886123 pthread_kill + 58
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x3b8c2973 abort + 94
3  libc++abi.dylib                0x3ae60d4f abort_message + 74
4  libc++abi.dylib                0x3ae5e0db safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 174
5  libc++abi.dylib                0x3ae5e114 std::terminate() + 19
6  libc++abi.dylib                0x3ae5f599 __cxa_current_exception_type
7  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3b4119d1 objc_exception_rethrow + 12
8  CoreFoundation                 0x336d7f21 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 456
9  CoreFoundation                 0x336d7d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
10 GraphicsServices               0x3728a2eb GSEventRunModal + 74
11 UIKit                          0x355ed301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
12 MyAppName                      0x000f1e9f main (main.m:15)
```

Comment: Can you post the complete crash log?

Comment: I added the complete crash in an edit.

Comment: @Jackson any news about this crash cause?

Answer (score 1):

as I see from the logs "pthread_kill" in the stack, I hope that this answer helps you.

[Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271421/exception-type-exc-crash-sigabrt)

Comment: Your link for "Exception Type" proved helpful to understanding this more.