# Running XC UI Tests fail to run (crash) on Xcode 9.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcuitest

I recently updated my Xcode to version 9.0.1 and after that I am not able to run any of XC UI Tests on my new Xcode. It looks like it is crashing with "libsystem_kernel.dylib __pthread_kill". Please see attached screenshot. 
Help is highly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkFWL.png)

Comment: I have encountered similar issues with Xcode 9.0.1. I haven’t been able to get specific, simplified reproduction steps to file a radar. You should try

Comment: Make sure that Enable Testability is set to Yes?
In the Project Navigator click your project  target . Select Build Settings and scroll down to Build Options. Make sure that Enable Testability is Yes (for debug).

Comment: @Tubelight: I changed Testing to YES in build Options but that didn't help. May be there is something I am missing I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having this issue, i have seen this once or twice before. This usually means bad data is being passed in by the application. Have a look here:

[Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271421/exception-type-exc-crash-sigabrt)

Check your full console output for where the bad data is coming from. Hope this helps!