# iOS crash: want to know what happened

Tags: ios, crash, sigabrt

Yesterday, the Photo's app crashed on my iPhone. I would like to know what happened and what caused the crash. I opened the app and it immediately crashed (black screen then back to springboard).

Before I opened the app, the iPhone was not "active" (sleep mode?). After the crash I opened the Photo's app again and then everything went well.

Can somebody guide me?

Thanks!

```
{"app_name":"MobileSlideShow","timestamp":"2018-12-16 18:52:13.05 +0100","app_version":"1.0.0","slice_uuid":"8950c678-7b32-3781-bf14-d3497bb7a065","adam_id":0,"build_version":"43","bundleID":"com.apple.mobileslideshow","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":true,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.1.1 (16C50)","incident_id":"E4C252A6-42C4-41B1-B0D7-5176AABB3DA6","name":"MobileSlideShow"}
Incident Identifier: E4C252A6-42C4-41B1-B0D7-5176AABB3DA6
CrashReporter Key:   b2ec6225f657c706fbb20e2f4f9bf08a14c3b3ae
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,4
Process:             MobileSlideShow [508]
Path:                /Applications/MobileSlideShow.app/MobileSlideShow
Identifier:          com.apple.mobileslideshow
Version:             43 (1.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.apple.mobileslideshow [500]


Date/Time:           2018-12-16 18:52:12.7099 +0100
Launch Time:         2018-12-07 13:29:19.4675 +0100
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1.1 (16C50)
Baseband Version:    2.02.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1c6e64ec4 0x1c6035a40 0x1c6d6b594 0x1d5c711ac 0x1d5c91e60 0x1da95f330 0x1da95f294 0x1da942454 0x1da961b4c 0x1da9f367c 0x1f3a12ad4 0x1f3a16e14 0x1f3a182d4 0x1f3a1beb4 0x1f45ef96c 0x1cb461b74 0x1cb466b2c 0x1f45dae58 0x1f3a32974 0x1f3a3285c 0x1f3a327e0 0x1f3a3271c 0x1da95e988 0x1da9417cc 0x1da95b2f4 0x1da941720 0x1da580110 0x1da57d9b0 0x1da580074 0x1da58b044 0x1da4d78c0 0x1da4d7640 0x1c791842c 0x1c6df51f0 0x1c6df5170 0x1c6df4a54 0x1c6def920 0x1c6def1f0 0x1c9068584 0x1f41474c0 0x1020bb240 0x1c68aebb4)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c69fb104 0x1c69d8000 + 143620
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a7b948 0x1c6a75000 + 26952
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001c6952d78 0x1c68fb000 + 359800
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001c601cf78 0x1c601b000 + 8056
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001c601d120 0x1c601b000 + 8480
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c6035e48 0x1c602f000 + 28232
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001c60290fc 0x1c601b000 + 57596
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001c6028cec 0x1c601b000 + 56556
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c6035c10 0x1c602f000 + 27664
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c6def25c 0x1c6d49000 + 680540
10  GraphicsServices                0x00000001c9068584 0x1c905d000 + 46468
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001f41474c0 0x1f385e000 + 9344192
12  MobileSlideShow                 0x00000001020bb240 0x1020b8000 + 12864
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001c68aebb4 0x1c68ae000 + 2996

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c69efea4 0x1c69d8000 + 97956
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c69ef37c 0x1c69d8000 + 95100
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c6df4be8 0x1c6d49000 + 703464
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c6defa84 0x1c6d49000 + 682628
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c6def1f0 0x1c6d49000 + 680432
5   Foundation                      0x00000001c77e5494 0x1c77dd000 + 33940
6   Foundation                      0x00000001c77e5340 0x1c77dd000 + 33600
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001f4237384 0x1f385e000 + 10326916
8   Foundation                      0x00000001c791823c 0x1c77dd000 + 1290812
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a8025c 0x1c6a75000 + 45660
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a801bc 0x1c6a75000 + 45500
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83cf4 0x1c6a75000 + 60660

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.ProGL.object-deletion
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c69faf0c 0x1c69d8000 + 143116
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a7d410 0x1c6a75000 + 33808
2   ProVideo                        0x00000001e6386438 0x1e6300000 + 549944
3   ProVideo                        0x00000001e68ac700 0x1e6300000 + 5949184
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a8025c 0x1c6a75000 + 45660
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a801bc 0x1c6a75000 + 45500
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83cf4 0x1c6a75000 + 60660

Thread 3 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c69efea4 0x1c69d8000 + 97956
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c69ef37c 0x1c69d8000 + 95100
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c6df4be8 0x1c6d49000 + 703464
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c6defa84 0x1c6d49000 + 682628
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c6def1f0 0x1c6d49000 + 680432
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001cce0260c 0x1ccd73000 + 587276
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001cce2e768 0x1ccd73000 + 767848
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a8025c 0x1c6a75000 + 45660
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a801bc 0x1c6a75000 + 45500
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83cf4 0x1c6a75000 + 60660

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 16 name:  Dispatch queue: PHChange-queue
Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c69efee0 0x1c69d8000 + 98016
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c686cb64 0x1c683d000 + 195428
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c686d5d4 0x1c683d000 + 198100
3   PhotosUICore                    0x00000001da4d7344 0x1da241000 + 2712388
4   Photos                          0x00000001d5bcaf60 0x1d5af1000 + 892768
5   Photos                          0x00000001d5b701b8 0x1d5af1000 + 520632
6   Photos                          0x00000001d5bca9fc 0x1d5af1000 + 891388
7   AssetsLibraryServices           0x00000001d4837ca0 0x1d482e000 + 40096
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c689d6c8 0x1c683d000 + 394952
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c689e484 0x1c683d000 + 398468
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c6878fa0 0x1c683d000 + 245664
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c6879ae4 0x1c683d000 + 248548
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c6881f04 0x1c683d000 + 282372
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a810dc 0x1c6a75000 + 49372
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83cec 0x1c6a75000 + 60652

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 24:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 25:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 26:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 27:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 28:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 29:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 30:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c6a83ce8 0x1c6a75000 + 60648

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000283684db7
    x4: 0x00000001c602cb81   x5: 0x000000016dd47620   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffff00020c00
    x8: 0x0000000000000800   x9: 0x00000001c6a7b820  x10: 0x00000001c6a76ea4  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x000000000000001b  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000047
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001021eab80  x21: 0x000000016dd47620  x22: 0x0000000000000407  x23: 0x00000001021eac60
   x24: 0x0000000281b10350  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016dd47c80   fp: 0x000000016dd47580   lr: 0x00000001c6a7b948
    sp: 0x000000016dd47550   pc: 0x00000001c69fb104 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash

Comment: I am no developer, just a user. I was curious what was happening so I posted it here. And so I do not know how to symbolicate a crash log. I found that you need Xcode but I do not know how to use that. And I probably don't have access to it since I'm no paying developer?

Comment: As a user without access to the source code, you will not be able to use this stack to debug the issue. (This particular stack would be difficult to figure out even with the source code because it's a generic "abort" stack.) That said, I'd check your system logs https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1747/_index.html. This app crashed due to an assertion failure, and there should be a message somewhere indicating what assertion failed. If you want to know what a symbolicated version of this looks like, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271421/exception-type-exc-crash-sigabrt

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, there's no way for me to know what was the cause of the crash since it's Apple's app and only they have the source code of the app? There's also no way to symbolicate the crash log?
What do you mean with "a generic abort stack"? And what is an assertion failure?

Answer (score 0):

All we can really know from this report is that the main thread threw an exception. To get more information, you'll need to symbolicate the report.

While it is true that you'll be unable to get source-level information, it is possible to symbolicate reports using Apple's binaries. If I'm not mistaken, Xcode does this automatically when it displays on-device logs. If you could make this happen again, you could try looking at the reports in the devices UI to see if does.

Manually symbolicating is going to be a real pain, but is definitely possible. Xcode saves symbol information to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport`. You'll need the *exact* matches for your OS -- 12.1.1 (16C50) in this case. These files are automatically created when you attach your device to Xcode for the first time.

From there, you can use tools like `atos` to symbolicate each line. Unfortunately, the most interesting lines are probably from the exception backtrace. And, those will involve you doing some math to figure out which library each frame belongs.

Long story short, it is technically possible to get more information here, and it *could* point you at a cause. But, it also may not, and will be a bunch of work. There might be a tool someone's made to do this, but I don't know of one unfortunately.

Comment: I have waited a bit to comment since I wanted to know if the app crashed again. It hasn't done so far so I won't put any more time in it. As I read your comment it will be quite an effort to find out without knowing if I'll know anything more. But thanks for your reply and the insight.

Comment: You are very welcome! Good luck - and don’t forget to enable crash report sharing with Apple, so at least they can get these reports too ;)